# c++ Templated Matrix class multiplication

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I'm kind of new to c++, so I want to understand why the following doesn't work or what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to make a matrix class using templates for its size and then apply some maths to the matrix or matrices.

In my main.cpp I have the following within the main method.

```
mat<4, 4> m = mat<4, 4>(1.0f); // Identity matrix

mat<2, 3> a = mat<2, 3>(2.0f); // Matrix with 2 rows & 2 columns
mat<3, 2> b = mat<3, 2>(3.0f); // Matrix with 3 rows & 2 columns
mat<3, 3> c = a * b; // Multiplication.

std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

With the matrix class stated beneath the multiplication works when both matrices have the same size for both the number of rows and columns (ie 3x3, 4x4, etc.). It's also legit to multiply 2 matrices of different sizes as long as the number of columns from matrix A is the same as the number of rows from matrix B (ie A<2, 3> * B<3, 2> = C<3, 3>). My matrix class only needs to be able to multiply matrices with the same size for both the number rows and columns (4x4 matrices for 3d maths). But I would like to know what I'm doing wrong or understand why this isn't working.

Matrix class:

```
template <int rows, int columns>
struct mat
{
    float elements[rows * columns];

    // Default constructor.
    mat()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            elements[i] = (float) 0.0f;
    }

    // Basic constructor
    mat(float diagonal) : mat()
    {
        int min = rows > columns ? columns : rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
            elements[i + i * columns] = diagonal;
    }

    /*************************
    * Helper functionalities *
    *************************/

    // Returns an identity matrix.
    // Should only be used when width and height are the same.
    static mat<4, 4> identity()
    {
        return mat<4, 4>(1.0f);
    }

    // Returns an orthographic matrix.
    static mat<4, 4> orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far)
    {
        mat<4, 4> result(1.0f);

        result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = 2.0f / (right - left);
        result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
        result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = 2.0f / (near - far);

        result.elements[0 + 3 * 4] = (left + right) / (left - right);
        result.elements[1 + 3 * 4] = (bottom + top) / (bottom - top);
        result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = (far + near) / (far - near);

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a perspective matrix.
    static mat<4, 4> perspective(float fov, float aspect, float near, float far)
    {
        mat<4, 4> result(1.0f);

        result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = (1.0f / tan(torad(0.5f * fov))) / aspect;
        result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = (1.0f / tan(torad(0.5f * fov)));
        result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = (near + far) / (near - far);

        result.elements[3 + 2 * 4] = -1.0f;
        result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = (2.0f * near * far) / (near - far);

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a translation matrix.
    static mat<4, 4> translation(const vec<3>& translation)
    {
        mat<4, 4> result(1.0f);

        result.elements[0 + 3 * 4] = translation.x;
        result.elements[1 + 3 * 4] = translation.y;
        result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = translation.z;

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a rotation matrix.
    static mat<4, 4> rotation(float angle, const vec<3>& axis)
    {
        mat<4, 4> result(1.0f);

        float radians = torad(angle);
        float c = cos(radians);
        float s = sin(radians);

        result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = axis.x * (1.0f - c) + c;
        result.elements[1 + 0 * 4] = axis.y * axis.x * (1.0f - c) + axis.z * s;
        result.elements[2 + 0 * 4] = axis.x * axis.z * (1.0f - c) - axis.y * s;

        result.elements[0 + 1 * 4] = axis.x * axis.y * (1.0f - c) - axis.z * s;
        result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = axis.y * (1.0f - c) + c;
        result.elements[2 + 1 * 4] = axis.y * axis.z * (1.0f - c) + axis.y * s;

        result.elements[0 + 2 * 4] = axis.x * axis.z * (1.0f - c) + axis.y * s;
        result.elements[1 + 2 * 4] = axis.y * axis.z * (1.0f - c) - axis.x * s;
        result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = axis.z * (1.0f - c) + c;

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a scale matrix.
    static mat<4, 4> scale(const vec<3>& scale)
    {
        mat<4, 4> result(1.0f);

        result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = scale.x;
        result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = scale.y;
        result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = scale.z;

        return result;
    }

    /***********************
    * Math functionalities *
    ***********************/

    // Overloaded addition operator to add two matrices together.
    friend mat<rows, columns> operator + (mat<rows, columns> left, const mat<rows, columns>& right)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            left.elements[i] += right.elements[i];
        return left;
    }

    // Overloaded addition operator to add a scalar to a matrix.
    friend mat<rows, columns> operator + (mat<rows, columns> left, const float& scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            left.elements[i] += scalar;
        return left;
    }

    // Overloaded add and assign operator to add a matrix to a matrix.
    mat<rows, columns>& operator += (const mat<rows, columns>& other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            elements[i] += other.elements[i];
        return *this;
    }

    // Overloaded add and assign operator to add a scalar to a matrix.
    mat<rows, columns>& operator += (const float& scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            elements[i] += scalar;
        return *this;
    }

    // Overloaded subtraction operator to subtract a matrix from another matrix.
    friend mat<rows, columns> operator - (mat<rows, columns> left, const mat<rows, columns>& right)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            left.elements[i] -= right.elements[i];
        return left;
    }

    // Overloaded subtraction operator to subtract a scalar from a matrix.
    friend mat<rows, columns> operator - (mat<rows, columns> left, const float& scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            left.elements[i] -= scalar;
        return left;
    }

    // Overloaded subtract and assign operator to subtract a matrix from a matrix.
    mat<rows, columns>& operator -= (const mat<rows, columns>& other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            elements[i] -= other.elements[i];
        return *this;
    }

    // Overloaded subtract and assign operator to subtract a scalar from a matrix.
    mat<rows, columns>& operator -= (const float& scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
            elements[i] -= scalar;
        return *this;
    }

    template<int rows, int equals, int columns>
    // Overloaded multiplication operator to multiply a matrix with another matrix.
    friend mat<rows, columns> operator * (const mat<rows, equals>& left, const mat<equals, columns>& right)
    {
        mat<rows, columns> result;

        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            {
                float sum = 0.0f;
                for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
                {
                    sum += left.elements[x + i * columns] * right.elements[i + y * columns];
                }

                result.elements[x + y * columns] = sum;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /*************************
    * Output functionalities *
    *************************/

    // Overloaded output operator to print the vector to output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, mat& matrix)
    {
        out << "mat<" << rows << ", " << columns << "> (" << std::endl;

        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            out << "\t";

            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            {
                out << matrix.elements[x + y * columns];

                if (x < columns - 1)
                    out << ", ";

                else
                    out << std::endl;
            }
        }

        return out << ")";
    }
};
```

EDIT as @filmor asked for compilation error: 
The error I'm getting is 
error C2995: 'mat operator *(const mat &,const mat &)' : function template has already been defined maths\matrix.h  190 1   Tests

Comment: What is not working? Do you get a compilation or runtime error? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving the friended operator* overloads outside of the class and thus removing 'friend' it works for both 3x3 * 3x3 and 2x3 * 3x2 matrices...

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code from operator* I see two errors: first of all you should iterate i over equals (not columns) and then left  matrix has `equals` columns, so you need to access its elements via `left.elements[x + i * equals]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
   sum += left.elements[x + i * columns] * right.elements[i + y * columns];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't solve my problem. The for loop iterates over equals now and left.elements is accessed using equals now. As filmor asked for the compiliation error I added it to my original post.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are trying to implement the multiplication as friend. Try a member function. In this case the only template parameter is the columns of right matrix. (*this is rows x colums, result is rows x right_columns)

Comment: I missed your comment, but you're right! Thanks for the help @marom